# app.ts is not rendering on plunkr

Tags: javascript, angular, plunker

I am new to angular and trying to follow a course but for some reason the app.ts(the only file I've modified in the plunkr angular boilerplate) won't render. Below is my code:

```
    //our root app component
import { Component, NgModule, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <form>
  <input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="model.search" ngControl="search" #inputSearch="ngForm">
  <p class="error" [hidden]="inputSearch.valid"> This input is required</p>


  </form>

  `,
  styles: [`
  .error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  `]
})
export class App {
  public model = {
    search: "" 
  }

  constructor() {

  }

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [App],
  bootstrap: [App],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is the error printout:

> gtm.js?id=GTM-T6RZMX:168 GET https://static.ads-twitter.com/oct.js 0
>   () match.adsrvr.org/tra…addthis&ttd_tpi=1:1 GET
>   https://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmf/generic?ttd_pid=addthis&ttd_tpi=1 0
>   () secure.adnxs.com/get…%24UID%26ssrc%3D1:1 GET
>   https://secure.adnxs.com/getuid?https%3A%2F%2Fsu.addthis.com%2Fred%2Fusync%3Fpid%3D6%26puid%3D%24UID%26ssrc%3D1
>   0 () VM4056 runtime.9ff15…16d788666a54a.js:16 GET
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/main.js 404 () VM4056
>   runtime.9ff15…16d788666a54a.js:16 GET
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/app.js 404 () VM4073
>   plugin.js:385 TypeScript [Error]
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/app.ts:33:14 VM4073
>   plugin.js:385 TypeScript [Error] ';' expected. (TS1005) VM4073
>   plugin.js:385 TypeScript [Error]
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/app.ts:33:24 VM4073
>   plugin.js:385 TypeScript [Error] ';' expected. (TS1005) VM4056
>   runtime.9ff15…16d788666a54a.js:16 Error: TypeScript transpilation
>   failed   Instantiating
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/app.js   Loading
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/main.js   Loading
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/main.js
>       at We.eval (VM4073 plugin.js:319)
>       at step (VM4073 plugin.js:77)
>       at Object.eval [as next] (VM4073 plugin.js:26)
>       at fulfilled (VM4073 plugin.js:7) editor-1.17.0.js:7 AUTH  {token: "6930491cbf9152a726a2d76cb6e0d81e784e67a0", id: 1596808, data: {…},
>   service: "github"} editor-1.17.0.js:2 Event tracked Plunk Restore
>   Sidebar undefined undefined runtime.9ff156e….js:16 GET
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/main.js 404 ()
>   runtime.9ff156e….js:16 GET
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/app.js 404 () plugin.js:385
>   TypeScript [Error]
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/app.ts:37:14 plugin.js:385
>   TypeScript [Error] ';' expected. (TS1005) plugin.js:385 TypeScript
>   [Error] https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/app.ts:37:24
>   plugin.js:385 TypeScript [Error] ';' expected. (TS1005)
>   runtime.9ff156e….js:16 Error: TypeScript transpilation failed
>   Instantiating https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/app.js
>   Loading https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/main.js   Loading
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/main.js
>       at We.eval (VM4073 plugin.js:319)
>       at step (VM4073 plugin.js:77)
>       at Object.eval [as next] (VM4073 plugin.js:26)
>       at fulfilled (VM4073 plugin.js:7)

Could it be that I'm trying to implement 2way data binding in an old way?

Comment: what errors do you see?

Comment: I just added the errors.

Comment: Appears to be missing a closing brace for `class App`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! it seems to have solved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated by Jonathan Lonowski, it was due to a missing clossing brace in the `class App`.